# Accessing children elements of html anchor with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to get inner spans in anchor elements similar to this:

```
<a href="#" class="joinCount">  
   <span class="data">3<span>
   <span class="text">Join</span>
</a>
```

I want to get value `3` and increment it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('a.joinCount > span.data').text(function(i,txt) { return +txt + 1; });
```

---

This will increment the number for ***every*** `a.joinCount > span.data` that is found, since it seems from the question that there's more than one of that structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a.joinCount .data").text(parseInt($("a.joinCount .data",10).text())+1)
```

Comment: Remember to use the radix option in `parseIn()`; otherwise you run the risk of ending up with octal values, instead of decimal: [parseInt('string',radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 2):

`$('a.joinCount span.data').text(parseInt($(this).text(), 10)+1);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var $span = $("a.joinCount span.data");
$span.text(1 + parseInt($span.text(), 10));
```

Don't forget to pass the radix of `10` to parseInt so that leading zeroes won't break your code (since parseInt would treat them as octal).

Comment: `1 + $span.text()` will return `13`.

Comment: @FelixKling - I though it would implicitly convert the text to an integer since you were saying 1 +

Comment: No, if either operand is a string, the result is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = jQuery('a.joinCount span.data').val();
```

if you want to increment the value in the span field, you can it as

```
jQuery('a.joinCount span.data').val(parseInt(jQuery('a.joinCount span.data').val()) + 1);
```